# Flex a circular hero button

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm working on a mobile website. This particular page includes a giant red circular hero button. I'm struggling to find a way to make it properly responsive. If you make it one size, it fits iPhone 5 nicely, but the same size pushes the rest of the page off the screen for iPhone 4. The iPhone 4 size just makes it look terrible and be too small on iPhone 5.

So the behaviour that I'm looking for is this:

- The hero button should get bigger in radius as the screen gets bigger
- The hero button should not push any other elements off the screen or render wider than it's container.
- The other parts of the page are a fixed size and layout and should stay that way.

I've used Flexbox for similar constraints in the past, but it doesn't seem to be fitting the bill here. When I make the container of the hero button a flexbox, it does not increase in height, and I have no idea how to make the width correspond.

How can I make the button expand to fill the available screen space?

Comment: But it's not going to fill the available space is it? It's constrained by its container...which has a fixed size...right?

Comment: Well, not ... really. The width is capped but the height is not. And the width cap is significantly wider than the device range I'm looking to support (at least in portrait mode). So for rendering on the different devices, then the width is not fixed and nor is the height.

Comment: Width is capped or fixed...if so, to what... a fixed px value or a % of the screen width? I'm thinking a demo might be useful.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Well, it's 100% of the screen width - some padding px normally, and then the cap is a fixed width in em.

Comment: Would `viewport units` be something useful here?

Comment: ... maybe actually we could calc() the desired size in terms of viewport units.

Comment: Well if the button is say 80vw wide (80%) then you could set the height to be the same and bingo, responsive circle...but I'm unsure as to how you want this to affect elements above and below it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to do this.

get the screen size by using `$(window).height()` and `$(window).height()` and set the size of your button accordingly

Comment: This would require manually re-sizing whenever the window resizes, which is not really ideal

Comment: You mean manually refreshing? you can use `$(window).resize()` too